# Transforming a column in an RDD/DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this line:

```
val decryptedDFData = sqlContext.read.json(patientTable.select("data").map(row => decrypt(row.toString())))
```

Which just selects the "data" column from another DataFrame "patientTable" and applies my decryption function row by row and creates another DataFrame. How can I either: Apply the encryption function to the original DataFrame knowing that the schema isn't going to be fixed (but the "data" attribute will always be there) or insert each row of the new DataFrame as a struct into it's corresponding row from before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use udf:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def decrypt(s: String) = s 
val decryptUDF = udf(decrypt _)

patientTable.select(col("*"), decryptUDF(col("data").cast(StringType)))
```